# how to update the model class recipe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have two model classes Category  and  Recipe  and their relationship in one to many. I want to Edit the Recipe and also change the category that the recipe  belongs to.Thanks in advance.

```
    public class CookContext : DbContext 
    {
        public CookContext(): base("cookContext")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
   }
     public class Category
     {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
     }

     public class Recipe
     {

         public int Id { get; set; }
         [Required]
         public string Title { get; set; }
         [Required]
         public string Description { get; set; }
         [Required]
         public string Ingridients { get; set; }

         public string Image { get; set; }

         public Category category { get; set; }
     }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult EditRecipe(Recipe recipe, int? categoryName)
    {
        var category = context.Categories.Where(c => c.Id == 
        (int)categoryName).FirstOrDefault();
        context.Entry(recipe).State = EntityState.Modified;
        recipe.category = category;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The error messages i get are:
1.
 [DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types.
2.
Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

Comment: Can you also post your DbContext class?

Comment: i posted the DbContext class

Comment: Do you have a field CategoryId in your Recipes table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by adding the field `CategoryId` to your `Recipe` class, also, the `category` property  should begin with a capital "C".

The collection property should be marked virtual if you want the data to be lazy loaded (only loaded when needed) otherwise, you may load all recipes for a given category every time you make a query:

```
public class Recipe
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Ingridients { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
}
```

If it doesn't work try by setting up the `ForeignKey` attribute:

```
public class Recipe
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Ingredients { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It worked but can you explain why it worked? why do i need the categoryId?

Comment: It is just a convention that EF uses to find out about your relationships, otherwise you need to manually specify it.